# Cross Product of vectors in 7 Dimensions

Tags: solid-geometry

While reading a geometry book I came across something like.......
***Cross Product is possible only in 3 Dimension system and 7 Dimension system.***
Why?(or How?)

Answer (score 2):

You probably won't like the answer, but ... this is a deep result. The first proof I saw of it was in Milnor and Stasheff's *Characteristic Classes*. To read that, you'll need to know about algebraic topology, at least at the level of Vick's *Homology Theory* book,  which'll require some abstract algebra (Herstein's book?)and to know about manifolds, perhaps at the level of Guillemin and Pollack's *Differential Topology* book. To read that will require a knowledge of a bit of point-set topology (Munkres book, first few chapters), and a good deal of multivariable calculus.

If I knew a simple explanation, I promise I would give it. :(